# Linux, awk and how to count and print consecutive lines in a file?

Tags: linux, shell, awk

For example I have a file like:

```
  apple
  apple
  strawberry
```

What I want to achieve is to print the consecutive line(apple) and count how many times it is consecutive(2) like this: apple-2 using awk.

My code so far is this however it does the following: apple1-apple1.

```
awk '{current = $NF;
getline;
if($NF == current) i++; 
printf ("%s-%d",current,i) }' $file
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: could you clarify what your input file looks like? your example suggests there's one line in the file, containing 3 words. Rather, does your file have 3 lines, and one word per line? Basically, is this the output you want: `uniq -c infile | awk '{ print $2 ,  $1 }'` ?

Comment: I'm very sorry, I mistyped my inputfile. Yes, you're right, I have only one word per line, so 3 lines.

Comment: is each word in line  preceded by hyphen `-` ?

Comment: No, I just wanted to make a list to show you, but I'm new to the site and I failed, apologies. @michael_n the output you gave me is almost what I want, but I want to print only the consecutive word(once) and how many times it's consecutive. Hope I'm making myself clear.

Comment: @MattPhilips you can edit the question and correctly format the input file, as you've done with the awk code.

Comment: Done it @michael_n!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `uniq -c` and awk for filtering:

```
$ uniq -c foo|awk '$1>1'
      2   apple
```

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
$ cat file
apple
apple
strawberry
mango
apple
strawberry
strawberry
strawberry
```

You can do:

```
$ awk '$1==last{seen[$1]++} 
               {last=$1}
       END{for (e in seen) 
            print seen[e]+1, e}' file
2 apple
3 strawberry
```

Comment: This does not work correctly, if you have e.g. two strawberries after the two apples. Output: 2 apple 4 strawberry

Comment: @Joseph I am unable to  reproduce that. If I have `echo $'apple\napple\nstrawberry\nstrawberry' | [that awk script]` it prints `2 apple
\n2 strawberry`

Comment: I meant replace these 4 lines with the first 3 of your `test` file, or add 2 or more `apple`s at the end and you'll see what happens.